# Showing that $(X_n,Y) \rightarrow (X,Y)$ weakly if $X_n \Rightarrow X$ stably

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, convergence-divergence

Let $E$ be a polish space, $X,Y,X_1,X_2,\ldots$ be $E$-valued r.v. s.t. $X_n \Rightarrow X$ stably, i.e.
$$
\forall f \in C_b(E,\mathbb{R}),\, \forall U \in B(\Omega,\mathbb{R}):\, \mathbb{E}[Uf(X_n)] \rightarrow \mathbb{E}[Uf(X)].
$$

Then $(X_n,Y) \rightarrow (X,Y)$ weakly.

The author of the paper I am reading states that this is trival but I can not see why. I would be grateful for hints or a solution.

Comment: You can probably first try showing it for $f(x,y) = 1_{x \in A} 1_{y \in B}$, using the fact that $U 1_{Y \in B}$ will also be Borel measurable, and then approximate f by simple functions?

Comment: I know that $X_n$ converges weakly, but how does that help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the definition of stable convergence, easy to get
\begin{equation*}
 \mathsf{E}[f(X_n)g(Y)] \to \mathsf{E}[f(X)g(Y)], \quad \forall f,g\in C_b(E,\mathbb{R}).
\end{equation*}
Now, just using the **Stone-Weierstrass Theorem**  have
\begin{equation*}
 \mathsf{E}[h(X_n,Y)]\to \mathsf{E}[h(X,Y)] \quad \forall h\in C_b(E\times E,\mathbb{R}).
\end{equation*}
That is $(X_n,Y)\to (X,Y)$ weakly.

Remark: About the stable convergence, please refer to  J. Jacod, and  A. N. Shiryayev, *Limit Theory for Stochastic Processes*, 2ed. Springer, 2003. p.512--.

Comment: Thanks! Which version of the Stone-Weierstrass Theorem do you use?

Comment: You are welcome. There are some negligence;  I write another proof in the following.

Answer (score 0):

In your definition of the stable convergence, you can trivially extend it to the case where $f$ and $U$ are complex-valued (by decomposing into real and imaginary parts).

In particular for $f(x)=\mathrm e^{iax}$ and $U=\mathrm e^{ibY}$, where $a,b\in\mathbb R$, you deduce that the characteristic function of $(X_n,Y)$ converges simply to that of $(X,Y)$, hence $(X_n,Y)$ converges to $(X,Y)$ weakly.

Comment: Yes I know this proof, but it works only for $E=\mathbb{R}^d$. Do you know a proof for general E?

Comment: Oh right sorry. Clearly you have $\mathbb E[f(X_n)g(Y)]\to\mathbb E[f(X)g(Y)]$ for all measurable and bounded maps $f,g:E\to\mathbb R$, and I thought it was almost trivial that it implies weak convergence of $(X_n,Y)$ to $(X,Y)$, but to be honest right now I can't find a simple proof when the random variables are $E$-valued. If $Z_n:\Omega\to E$ converges weakly to $Z$ and $(h_k:E\to\mathbb R)_k$ is a nondecreasing sequence of measurable and bounded maps which converges to some measurable map $h$, do we have $\mathbb E[h(Z_n)]\to\mathbb E[h(Z)]$? If so then you have an easy proof

Answer (score 0):

From the definition of stable convergence(About the stable convergence, please refer to  J. Jacod, and  A. N. Shiryayev, *Limit Theory for Stochastic Processes*, 2ed. Springer, 2003. p.512--. ), easy to get
\begin{equation*}
 \mathsf{E}[f(X_n)g(Y)] \to \mathsf{E}[f(X)g(Y)], \quad \forall f,g\in C_b(E,\mathbb{R}).
\end{equation*}
Now, if the space $E$ is compact, then using the Stone-Weierstrass
Theorem(c.f.  S. Willard, *General Topology*, Addison-Wesley Publish Company, (1970), p.291, Th.44.5) we have
\begin{equation*}
 \mathsf{E}[h(X_n,Y)]\to \mathsf{E}[h(X,Y)] \quad \forall h\in C_b(E\times E,\mathbb{R}).
 \tag{1}
\end{equation*}
Generally, if $E$ is a Polish space, using the tightness of distributions of $\{(X_n,U),\,n\ge 1\}$, for each $\varepsilon>0 $, there exists a compact set $K^{\varepsilon}\times K^{\varepsilon}\subset E\times E$ such that
\begin{equation*}
 \sup_n\mathsf{P}((X_n,U)\in (K^{\varepsilon}\times K^{\varepsilon})^c )<\varepsilon, \quad
 \mathsf{P}((X,U)\in (K^{\varepsilon}\times K^{\varepsilon})^c )<\varepsilon, 
 \tag{2}
\end{equation*}
Hence, for each $h\in C_b(E\times E,\mathbb{R})$ with $|h|\le b$, we have
\begin{align*}
 &|\mathsf{E}[h(X_n,Y)]-\mathsf{E}[h(X,Y)] |\\
 &\le |\mathsf{E}[h(X_n,Y)I_{\{(X_n,Y)\in (K^{\varepsilon}\times K^{\varepsilon})\}}] -\mathsf{E}[h(X,Y)I_{\{(X,Y)\in (K^{\varepsilon}\times K^{\varepsilon})\}}] | +4b\varepsilon.
\end{align*}
Furthermore, using (1)($E=K^\varepsilon$ is compact),
\begin{align*}
 -4b\varepsilon +\mathsf{E}[h(X,Y)]&\le \varliminf_{n\to\infty}\mathsf{E}[h(X_n,Y)]\\
 &\le \varlimsup_{n\to\infty}\mathsf{E}[h(X_n,Y)]\le \mathsf{E}[h(X,Y)]+4b\varepsilon .
\end{align*}
letting $\varepsilon\downarrow 0 $, (1) hold for the case of $E$ is Polish.
That is $(X_n,Y)\to (X,Y)$ weakly.

Comment: Sorry for the late question but how do you get the inequalities before the last line?